# White Line in Console Application

Tags: windows, console-application, windows-console

I am creating an console application which take response from server and update information and send back response to server.
During running that exe it shows white line on console.
I stuck to find the solution.

Please refer image for clearity.
[Console Application contains WhitLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuOBI.png)

Comment: Just on your computer do the white lines appear? Even after restart?

Comment: Yes i restarted my computer but issue still exists

Comment: No it is not on my computer i tested on three computer on which two have comming

Comment: Does a simple `Console.WriteLine` produce the same white lines? Try to narrow down the root cause by starting from a very simple console application then gradually add more and more functionality until you reach your application's current state.